# Unable to dequeue a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Having an issue with TableView like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
        let cell: UITableViewCell = autoCompleteTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let index = indexPath.row as Int

        cell.textLabel!.text = tableArray[index]

        return cell


    }
```

When I run the app I get: `"unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"`. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I'm not using the storyboard for this UITableView

Comment: Did you set the `cellReuseIdentifier` as the Identifier for the prototype cell in your `UITableView` inside the storyboard?

Comment: I'm not using the storyboard for this UITableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using a storyboard, then you can create default UITableViewCell with your cellIdentifier:

```
UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

This code attempts to find a `UITableViewCell` with the given identifier. Failing to do so, it creates a new `UITableViewCell` with the given identifier and adds it to the `UITableView`.

Comment: Ah got it. Sorry, haven't ever created a table in code before so got confused. Will this method still take advantage of reusing the cells if they are still available then?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer to explain how it works :)

Comment: Just saw your edit. Awesome thanks. Will accept in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Give the identifier of your custom cell. 
As per your code `let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"`
it should be `cell`

If you are not using `Storyboard` then you have to register your custom cell

`[self.tableView registerClass: [CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];`

[image]

Comment: Sorry I should of said, I'm not using the storyboard for this UITableView

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewDidLoad` or wherever you want (you have to run it only once), you must register the identifier, also for `UITableViewCell`

```
autoCompleteTableView.registerClass(
    UITableViewCell.self,
    forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your original code, because it's much better solution than:

```
UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

Only thing you need to do yet is registering your UITableViewCell class in `viewDidLoad()`

```
    self.autoCompleteTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

then just use your original code in cellForRow:

```
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
let cell: UITableViewCell = autoCompleteTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```